# Show $T|_{M}$ is a compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $T$ be a compact operator and suppose $M$ is an invariant subspace
for $T$. I need to show that $T|_M$ is compact.

Any hint on how to begin with this problem?

Comment: What definition of a compact operator are you working with?

Comment: Got the complete definition!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T$ (defined on $X$) is compact is equivalent to saying that the image of the unit ball is contained in a compact set. The unit ball of $M$ is a closed subset of the unit ball of $X$, so the adherence of its image is contained in the adherence of the image of the unit ball of $X$ so it is compact.